# WebAPI - to accept invalid JSON

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I have developed WebAPI with one class in which I can pass json and my class auto fills all values.

But sometimes, end user passes invalid data or junk data due to which my object returns as a null.

I need to record each requests regardless valid or invalid for my records.

How can I do that?

Comment: _due to which my object returns as a null_ do you mean the object received in the action is null?

Comment: yes object returned as null

Comment: What do you mean by _object returned as null_?

Comment: If you want to record all requests, use custom `DelegatingHandler` and register it gloabally.https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/http-message-handlers

Answer (score -2):

If you provide any code of some your implementation the answer may be more accurate.

Generally if you have a class to serialize / deserialize in JSON one way may be:

```
public class Response
{
    public bool success { get; set; }
    public string data { get; set; } 
    public string timestamp { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Using Newtonsoft JSON serializer to Deserialize a json string to it's corresponding class object.

```
try
{
    var jsonInput = "{success:true,data:'hello', timestamp:'123123123'}"; /*Request at you API*/
    Response response = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(jsonInput);
}
catch(Exception)
{
    // handle here bad request
}
```

Comment: This will cause the model to be deserialized twice: once by the model binder, and once by this code. You'll also have to copy-paste this code to every action method. Also, the default serializer doesn't have to be the JSON serializer. Also, you're ignoring serializer settings that may have been set at a higher level.